# Android: notifyDataSetChanged() is not working in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a part of code in a `Fragment`.

```
private AlarmOptionItemListAdapter listAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_new_alarm, null);

    listAdapter = new AlarmOptionItemListAdapter();
    ListView lvAlarmOptionList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvAlarmOptionList);
    lvAlarmOptionList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    initializeListItems();

    ...

    return view;
}

private void initializeListItems() {
    itemAlarmLock = new TextOnlyItem();
    itemAlarmLock.setTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_lock));
    itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.choose_option));
    listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmLock);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now, I overrode the `onActivityResult()` method in this `Fragment`. From this code I plan to change the text in the `ListView`'s item.

This `onActivityResult()` gets data from other `Fragment`s. With the brought data I try to replace the text in the `ListView`'s item with the new one.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case CODE_PIN:
                String value = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
                if(value != null) {
                    Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "PIN set to " + value);
                    itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.pin));
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;

            case CODE_PASSWORD:
                String password = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
                if(password != null) {
                    Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "Password set to " + password);
                    itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.password));
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;

            case CODE_PATTERN:
                String pattern = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
                if(pattern != null) {
                    Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, "Pattern set to " + pattern);
                    itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.pattern));
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I found out that the `Log` was properly showing, but somehow the list view does not change the value.

What should I modify to make it work?

Comment: you are notifying the adapter, but I cannot see where you are adding or editting items to it in onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code will solve your problem:

In FragmentB,where you are calling startActivityForResult(),write like below:

```
     getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,MainActivity.CODE_PIN);
```

Now,in Activity's startActivityForResult()

```
     @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case CODE_PIN:
            String value = data.getStringExtra(Keys.VALUE);
            if(value != null) {
            Fragment reference = null;
            List<Fragment> fragmentList =      getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
            for (int i = 0; i < fragmentList.size(); i++) {
                reference = fragmentList.get(i);
                if (reference != null && reference instanceof FragmentA) {
                    ((FragmentA) reference).refresh();
                }
            }
            }
            break;
          // Same for others REQUEST_CODE's
              }
}
}
```

In FragmentA,refresh the list as follows:

```
   public void refresh()
 {
        itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.pin));
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have declared a String ressources in your `strings.xml` called "pin", "password" and "pattern"?

Maybe I understand your code wrong but it seems you trying this:

`R.string.<value of variable>` ("pin", "password", "pattern" in your case)
this will not work.
Instead you only need to do this:

```
String variable = // your value
...
itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(variable);
```

I hope I understand your code correctly and this will help

Comment: Of course I already have those string resources in the `strings.xml` file.

Comment: Oh ok. then it is just shown in a bad way by the website :)